# Nil when passing information with NSNotifications?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I've got a class that controls dragging UIButtons on the screen. I'm wanting to capture the tag/final position of the button on touchesEnded.

I've got in my DragImageClass:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let dict =  ["position":String(self.center),"tag": String(self.tag)]

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("buttonDropped", object: nil, userInfo: dict)

    print(dict["position"]) // Does get printed
    print("Should have sent") // Does get called
}
```

then in my main view where I'm needing the info I've got :

My observer:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(testController.touchesStopped(_:)), name: "buttonDropped", object: nil)
```

My function:

```
func touchesStopped(notif : AnyObject) {
    if let dict = notif.object as? NSDictionary { //Some error with this data type I guess?
        let position = dict["position"]
        let tag = dict["tag"]
        print(position)  // doesn't get printed
        print(tag) // doesn't get printed
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I'm getting nil back from those values? When I try to force unwrap it's just giving me the "Thread bad instruction" thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in your call, the object is nil because you pass the dictionary as the `userInfo` (which is the right way to do it) :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("buttonDropped", object: nil, userInfo: dict)
```

So in order to get that dictionary back, don't use the `object` property of the notification, use the `userInfo` property :

```
func touchesStopped(notif: NSNotification) {
    if let dict = notif.userInfo {
        let position = dict["position"]
        let tag = dict["tag"]
        print(position)
        print(tag)
    }
}
```

Side note: Converting a point to a string and back to a point is going to be a pain, you should probably use `NSValue` instead like this :

```
let dict: [String:AnyObject] = [
    "position": NSValue(CGPoint: self.center),
    "tag": self.tag
]
let position = (dict["position"] as? NSValue)?.CGPointValue()
let tag = dict["tag"] as? Int
```

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense. I switched it up and I'm still getting an error that says that .userInfo is being used ambiguously?

Comment: See my edit, the notification must be declared as `NSNotification`, not `AnyObject`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation, `NSNotification.userInfo` is imported into Swift as `[NSObject: AnyObject]?`. Try this instead:

```
guard let notif = notif as? NSNotification,
   let dict = notif.userInfo as? [NSObject: AnyObject] else {
    return
}

let position = dict["position"]
let tag = dict["tag"]

print(position)  // doesn't get printed
print(tag) // doesn't get printed
```

Comment: No change in the output. Still getting the initial print outs of what should be getting sent over but I'm not getting anything out from the observer.

Comment: @deadbeef got it. There's a typo. Use `userInfo` instead of `object`.

Comment: When copypasting that directly in I get an error that says "Ambiguous use of userinfo". It shows up on autocomplete as an option just like .object so that makes no sense to me haha.

Comment: because you are passing in type AnyObject,  needs to be NSNotification

Comment: Let me clean it up.

Comment: Haha, thanks for the group effort here guys. It's working. Appreciate all the help